# c# Xamarin Android WebView fit to landscape screen

Tags: c#, android, xaml, webview, xamarin.android

Following the answer in the following link
"
[Xamarin WebView scale to fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154722/xamarin-webview-scale-to-fit) "

I've managed to fit the html live stream to the phone screen while it is in portrait mode. The result in portrait is acceptable. But **when the screen rotates to landscape mode** it exceeds the limits of the screen and in order to view the whole stream **it requires for the user to scroll.** I've found the following topic but it does not seem to work
[Xamarin webview does not fill screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57994990/xamarin-webview-does-not-fill-screen?rq=1)

What needs to be done in order for the stream to fit without scrolling. I feel that its simply. Do I follow the correct path?

I am using a **custom renderer for the WebView**

```
 public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected  override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
                Control.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = false;
                Control.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);

                Control.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
                Control.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;

            }
            /*
             * The code for the second link
             * 
             * Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
               Control.EvaluateJavascript("document.documentElement.style.height = screen.height + 'px';", null);
               Control.EvaluateJavascript("document.documentElement.style.width = screen.width + 'px';", null);
             */
        }
    }
```

**The xaml code of the page is**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage 
    NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:androidclient="clr-namespace:AndroidClient"
             x:Class="AndroidClient.LiveViewPage">

        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Button  x:Name="ExitFullScreenBtn" Clicked="ExitFullScreenBtn_Clicked"
                    HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="50"
                    Text="X"></Button>

        <androidclient:CustomWebView x:Name="Browser"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                 ></androidclient:CustomWebView>
    </StackLayout>
    

</ContentPage>
```

**The c# for the same page**

```
 [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LiveViewPage : ContentPage
    {
        public LiveViewPage()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();

            var url = "http://192.168.1.7:8080/";
            Browser.Source = url;        }

        private void ExitFullScreenBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Closed Live");
            Navigation.PopAsync();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I checked the code you provided with the url of this case link. In portrait mode, it fit the width of the screen and i could scroll to the bottom. On landscape mode, it fit the height of the screen and i also couls scroll to the bottom. Without your `http://192.168.1.7:8080/`, i am not sure what does `it requires for the user to scroll` mean. Do you mean you want to show all the page on the screen on landscape mode without scrolling?

Comment: Yes I don't want to scroll. I want the whole page to fit on screen. The url is a LAN broadcast from another device. Based on the `custom render's code` it works well on portrait but when I flip the screen to landscape mode It's like the webview is stretched or zoomed, so it does not fit on screen based on it's  size.

Comment: You could change the layout when you rotates to landscape mode. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/device-orientation?tabs=windows

Comment: In portrait works well. From portrait to landscape the screen does not fit well. But when I go back from landscape to portrait it works as well as before. Before the corrections in my code it didn't work I portrait either. With the correction (above) it works in portrait but not in landscape